# Drag and Drop feature for tools is possible in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I am still a new for Python GUI programming.
I have used winforms from .net before.

In .net for creating any controls ( textbox , lablel , buttons ..etc ) we just have to drag that tool from the tool box and add it to my designer.

Same kind of mechanism is possible in Python ( Tkinter or any other framework )

For adding any control(for ex label ) we have to give the position manually.

Is it possible to drag and drop the tools instead of creating manually ???

I am using VS Code as IDE.

Thank you...

Comment: Don't uses absolute positioning in tkinter, but use the layout managers. VSC is not an IDE but an editor with benefits. If you want this you can write an extension for this, a nice project.